# XPODataSource: Select from TableValuedFunctions

Tags: devexpress, xpo

Is it possible to select from a tabled-valued function using xpoDataSource instead of selecting from a table.

note: Im using xpoDatasource with serverMode = true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Source** - [Table Valued Function in XPO (and XAF)?](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q447461)

You can accomplish this task via direct SQL queries. Here is an example:

```
IDataLayer dal = XpoDefault.GetDataLayer(MSSqlConnectionProvider.GetConnectionString("(local)", "TestDatabase"), AutoCreateOption.None);
Session session = new Session(dal);
SelectedData data = session.ExecuteQueryWithMetadata("SELECT * FROM TrackingItemsModified(2)");
XPDataView view = new XPDataView();
foreach (var row in data.ResultSet[0].Rows) {
    view.AddProperty((string)row.Values[0], DBColumn.GetType((DBColumnType)Enum.Parse(typeof(DBColumnType), (string)row.Values[2])));
}
view.LoadData(new SelectedData(data.ResultSet[1]));
GridControl control = new GridControl();
control.DataSource = view;
control.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
Form form = new Form();
form.Controls.Add(control);
form.ShowDialog();
```

Reference these:
[How to populate an XPServerCollectionSource/InstantFeedbackCollectionSource with a runtime designed SQL statement result?](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q483231)
[How to pass a table valued parameter to Session.ExecuteSProc method](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q507925)